# Is possible to control CSS rules to not allow another rules to change it?

Tags: html, css

For example:

You have this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myrule {
  font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<div class="myrule">
  This text will bold but 
</div>


<style type="text/css">
.myrule {
  font-weight:normal; /* This code will affect the original .myrule */
}
</style>
```

What I need to know if is possible to "lock" CSS rules like this example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myrule:locked {
  color:yellow;
}
</style>
<div class="myrule">
   This text will yellow always!!!!!!!
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.myrule {
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Add ur CSS in tag it self , then it will add that rule to only that tag Ex:<input style="width:20px">

Comment: You should better fix your rules and imports though

Comment: For any of the `!important` answers, also notice the [precedence of properties, regarding !important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. You can use the `!important` operator to add an extreme weight to the CSS rule that will override pretty much anything else. However, another rule that is more specific that *also* has the `!important` operator will still override it.

Your best bet is not to try and "lock" CSS rules, per say, but to actually make sure that the rule's selector is always more specific than others. An ID selector is a great way to dominate specificity, and you will run into far fewer problems this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.myrule {
  font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to define an ID for your DIV tag, like

```
<div class="myrule" id="firstdiv">
   This text will yellow always!!!!!!!
</div>
```

then you can specify your id specific CSS rule, like

```
<style type="text/css">
#firstdiv .myrule {
  color:yellow;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think css interpretation differs by browser.  If you want to override css precedence, I think you need to use javascript to explicitly state your intent.